# Trigger Database Update during Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a single azure pipeline that triggers when I check work in. The pipeline works fine and goes to two separate release pipelines, one a sandbox and one a live state each have individual connection strings and corresponding Azure Web App services. When I load up either of the web apps via their urls I cannot log in and it seems that the Databases on SQL have not been updated. Is there any way to run

```
D:\a\9\s\(projectName).Blazor.Server\bin\Release\net5.0\(projectNmae).Blazor.Server.exe - updateDatabase - silent -forceUpdate
```

as a script during the release stage of the pipeline after the connection string has been set?

Comment: So far I have found a work around, you need to do a manual -updateDatabase in the App Service Editor. Hopefully this will help anyone with the same issue, still trying to find a way to automate this process and will update if I find anything. This is the console command I used to manually update the data base: C:\home\site\wwwroot\ 
 (projectName).Blazor.Server.exe -updateDatabase -silent -forceUpdate

Answer (score 1):

How about running a [Schell Script Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/shell-script?view=azure-devops) with `dotnet ef database update`